# Ruby on Rails - coffeescript $.post statement causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Within coffescript code I have

app/assets/javascript/drill.js.coffee

```
...
$('document').ready ->
  if $('#x_eval_assum').length == 1
    $('#x_eval_assum')  
      .submit (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        data = $("#x_eval_assum").serialize()
        drill_id = $('.form.assumption').attr('data-drillid')
        $.post "/drills/#{drill_id}/discovery_target_saved.json", data, (res)->
           console.log(' here ')
      .change (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
...
```

app/controller/drills_controller.rb

```
...
  def discovery_target_saved
    load_evaluation_assumption_selections
    load_user_positions
    render :json, {data: @drill.id}
  end
```

In Developer Tools Console I see this error
POST .. host:3000/drills/13/discovery_target_saved.json 500 (Internal Server Error)

Have tried a number of variations - what am I doing wrong ?

More stuff

Both "load_evaluation_assumption_selections" and "load_user_positions" are Drill Controller actions that are working correctly and are used by other Drill actions.

I currently have another error showing on the internal log- specifically

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 46ms
```

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template drills/json, application/json with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/davidlee/drill_investor/app/views"
  * "/Users/davidlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/views"
:
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:124:in`find

Comment: Is there some output, maybe this internal error, on the server console? What are you doing in `load_evaluation_assumption_selections` and `load_user_positions`. I guess we can't answer the question, because there is not enough information from your side.

Comment: is `@drill` getting set in the controller? If not then you'll get a `no method error` when you call `.id` on `@drill`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your url will work. Try replacing your `$.post` line with this version: `$.post "/drills/#{drill_id}/discovery_target_saved", data, (res)-> console.log('here'), "json"`

Comment: Working shutting up eerly but will try as soonasIreturn tommorror- Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is looking for a view template named `:json`. Try this in the controller instead:

```
def discovery_target_saved
  load_evaluation_assumption_selections
  load_user_positions
  render json: {data: @drill.id}
end
```